# What does the cntk.blocks.Stabilizer() function do in CNTK?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

I am going throught the [CNTK 204: Sequence to Sequence Networks with Text Data](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_204_Sequence_To_Sequence.ipynb) tutorial. A function cntk.blocks.Stabilizer() is used, but there is currently no documentation for that function. Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implement self stabilized from:

```
Self-stabilized deep neural network," P. Ghahremani and J. Droppo, ICASSP 2016
```

And here a direct link to the paper: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/SelfLR.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We will update the tutorial with more information.

Comment: Thanks. Just read the paper. Sounds like a great feature. From what I understand, this could be added to any deep neural network, not just recurrent neural networks, right? Also, the best way to use it would be to include it after each layer, similar to Batch Normalization? Would this replace Batch Normalization?

Comment: The stabilizer has, in my experience, always led to at least some improvement of convergence speed. However, Batch Normalization has also always been more effective; but Batch Normalization cannot be effectively used inside recurrent loops. For example in a language-processing scenario with multiple recurrent LSTM layers, my guideline would be: (1) use BatchNormalization between layers; (2) use stabilizer inside the recurrent step function (on h and c) but not on the input (x) since that is already normalized by BatchNorm.